# How to predict using UCM in R

Tags: r, predict

I want to predict sales using the ucm function. How can I make predictions when I have indipendent
variables inside the model. The model I am fitting is the following:

```
  model1<-ucm(Sales~Var1+Var2+Var3, data=Sales, etc)
```

How can I make predictions for example for 100 obs for which I have the values of Var1, Var2 and Var3 
but I do not have historical data for the sales.